# Is there a way to connect an Android app to a SAP database

Tags: android, netweaver

I'm developing an Android application for internal communication purposes.

The company has a SAP software, so the app should be connected to this SAP software.

Investigating through the web, I found a lot of ways for creating the app using the SAP Mobile Platform, but I'm looking for a simple and cheap way that doesn't require licensing.

Are there any option for connecting to a SAP database from Android?
What should be the approach like?

I'm kind of new to SAP landscape, so any tip will be welcomed.

EDIT: 
I think, one approach could be to develop a Web Service in SAP and expose it. Then consume it from the app.
Is this good enough?

Comment: SAP is a huge company with hundreds of software. What is the name of this SAP software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SAP system has API:s available for consumption over HTTP. You can connect to any of those or have an SAP developer create dedicated API:s for your use case. Normally they come as Web Services or OData services.

As long as your mobile device is on the same network as the SAP system, API:s can easily be consumed. If not, this turns into an infrastructure project as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of `SAP Cloud Platform SDK for Android`. No more knowledge on this. Please check below link, it may be helped.

https://www.sap.com/developer/trials-downloads/additional-downloads/sap-cloud-platform-sdk-for-android-15508.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that service requires licensing!

Comment: Consuming the SAP data from an external app will require licensing in almost any situation.